# Use a variable in update statement ASP.NET in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, variables

I want to use variable name as column name in ASP.NET column name.

I'm getting the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'February'.

The code is

```
SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\apptitude\projects\database\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        MyConn.Open();
        int i,n=5;
        String[] month=new String[12]{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","Octomber","November","December"};
        int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        int mon= DateTime.Now.Month;
        Label1.Text = day.ToString();
        if (day==1)
        {
            //for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //{
            //Label1.Text = "hi";
            int j = 1;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = MyConn;
            cmd.CommandText = "update Yearly_data set **'"+month[mon]+"'=20";**
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What's up with the asterisks and single quotes?

Comment: @antisanity - I'm guessing the asterisks were added when formatting in SO to make the text bold. It doesn't work for code segments though, and just displays the double asterisks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to enclose column names in single quotes ('); hence this:

```
update Yearly_data set 'February'=20
```

Should be written as

```
update Yearly_data set February=20
```

If you change your code to the below, it will work:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Yearly_data set "+month[mon]+"=20";
```

However, note that building Dynamic SQL statements is something that should be carefully done as not to risk your app on a [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

If every month of the year is a ColumnName in `Yearly_data` then change your line of code to:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Yearly_data set ["+month[mon]+"]=20";
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already given, the framework provides a way to get the name of the month using the [DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) function.

```
static string GetMonthName(DateTime sourceDate)
{
    var dateFormatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    return dateFormatInfo.GetMonthName(sourceDate.Month);
}

cmd.CommandText = String.Format("update Yearly_data set {0} = 20", GetMonthName(DateTime.Now));
```